# What does "something eats into somebody" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does **it eats into you** mean? I have read this in a play

> It eats you, which is normal

I like to know what the meaning is and how many meaning I can consider for it.

Comment: Having the context of the whole sentence would be helpful.  Having something "eat at you" is more idiomatic so seeing the quote and knowing the source would help us help you. :-)

Comment: What is the deal with the title of this post?

Comment: @Oldcat Ssssnake ssssspeak? -- Yeah, I've been wondering that too. Maybe there's some popular EFL textbook using stuff like that, or maybe an EFL grammar site, or . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eat into:

to destroy or waste gradually. Acid eats into metal; The school fees have eaten into our savings.

It is necessary to understand the wider context of your sentence, anyway I think that the meaning given above can help you.